# Path with backslashes to path with forward slashes javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, backslash

I'm trying to make a **local** xml file parsing "application" for some colleagues and i'm using the current function to retrieve the files:

```
function ShowFolderFileList(folderspec) {
    var fso, f, f1, fc, s;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec);
    fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
    s = "";
    for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
        var pathString = fc.item();
        $("#test").append(pathString + "<br />");
    }
}
```

The problem with this function it returns a string similar to:

```
C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\cool\Archief\CDATA1.xml
```

I need to replace the backward slashes to forward slashes of the entire string. 
How to do this?

I tried the replace method:

```
pathString.replace(/\\/g, "/")
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: How did you do your replace call? Could you add that to your example?

Comment: If a provided answer solved your problem, please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 20):

The `replace` method does not alter the current instance of the string, but returns a new one. See if this works:

```
pathString = pathString.replace(/\\/g,"/");
```

See [this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWCAn/).

Comment: This only works because you've changed the output from the OP. He never had double slashes in his path. A single slash get's treated as an escaped character so your replace will not work.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm quite sure that `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` creates valid paths with properly escaped slashes.

Comment: I agree that a non-escaped string won't work, as your example states. But then again, I'm quite sure that the OP's string _is_ properly escaped since in the OP's example shows it's created by a Microsoft library that provides file system access.

Answer (score 3):

If in your string you do not have two backslashes and **ONLY** one backslash, you can use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```js
var myString = String.raw`C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\cool\Archief\CDATA1.xml`;
console.log(myString.replace(/\\/g, '/'));
```